# IoT-Agent OPC-UA Docker-compose setting for NGSI ld or NGSI v2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fiware, opc-ua, opc

In the docker-composer files of the [OPC-UA IoT-Agent](https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua) there are some comments unclear to me, in particular [at the line](https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua/blob/c71ea2419346a11f6473fe0cde21811bcf03cb4e/docker-compose.yml#L35) is told to comment if you want to use NGSI-LD or to comment [the line](https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua/blob/c71ea2419346a11f6473fe0cde21811bcf03cb4e/docker-compose.yml#L37) if you want to use NGSI-V2.

Reading the strings that should be commented out however, it would seem that it is necessary to remove the comments from both the lines to use NGSI-LD, and comment both of them to use NGS-V2.

Is my interpretation correct? Thanks for clearing it up.

PS: the same issue is present to the file docker-compose-external-server.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up NGSI-v2 vs NGSI-LD is common to all IoT Agents. The [Installation Guide](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installationguide.html) describes the required configuration - default operation is NGSI-v2.

If you want to operate NGSI-LD, the `ngsiVersion` and `jsonLdContext` must be defined.

```js
{
    host: '192.168.56.101',
    port: '1026',
    ngsiVersion: 'ld',
    jsonLdContext: 'http://context.json-ld' 
}
```

`ngsiVersion` can be `v2`, `ld` or `mixed`.

Both settings can also be set up using [Environment Variables](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installationguide.html#configuration-using-environment-variables) which is more convenient when using Docker

Therefore, for NGSI-LD the following minimal set-up is required:

```yaml
  iotage:
    hostname: iotage
    image: iotagent4fiware/iotagent-opcua:latest
    environment:
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=ld
      - IOTA_JSON_LD_CONTEXT=https://path-to-context-file
      - IOTA_FALLBACK_TENANT=opcua_car
      - IOTA_RELAX_TEMPLATE_VALIDATION=true
```

For NGSI-v2 the following is required:

```yaml
  iotage:
    hostname: iotage
    image: iotagent4fiware/iotagent-opcua:latest
    environment:
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2
      - IOTA_RELAX_TEMPLATE_VALIDATION=true
```

`IOTA_RELAX_TEMPLATE_VALIDATION` is required for OPC-UA to allow the provisioning of OPC-UA topics with `=` within them which would normally be disallowed.